# unison sync files in directory but not folders

Tags: linux, unison

How can i tell unison given a sync path /home/user/mydata
to only sync

```
/home/user/mydata/file.txt
/home/user/mydata/data.txt
but not
/home/user/mydata/subfolder
```

I've simplified the question to this example but is there a way to tell it to sync only files at a specific path?

Comment: are you specifying recursive flags( -a or -r?). Skip them

Answer (score 0):

In your profile for that directory you can do something like

```
ignore = Path subfolder
```

For more examples take a look at the example [here](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/apps/unison.hints)

Comment: Downvoted for requiring to explicitly enumerate all subdirectories. Also link dead.